# Программная отметка CheckBox`a

Tags: android, checkbox, recyclerview

Добрый день. У меня есть RecyclerView, который выводит списоком CardView. Каждая CardView состоит из TextView и CheckBox. Отмечать CheckBox нажатием по самому CheckBox не очень удобно(потому что площадь чекбокса мала для пальца). Хотелось бы сделать отметку CheckBoxa нажатием по всему CardView. Посадил RecyclerView на ClickListner:

```
         rv.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(),
     rv, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Click" + 
AddFilterAdapter.getBox(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }   
                }));
```

Далее, как мне кажется, нужно в адаптаре определить позицию CardView и чекнуть нужный CheckBox по позиции. Но как это реализовать? Подскажите примером.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете добавить логику чекбокса прямо во view holder,  например

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

private View itemView ;
private CheckBox checkbox;

public ViewHolder(View itemView){
super(itemView) 
this.itemView=itemView;
this.checkbox =(CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox)
} 

void bindItem(RecyclerView item, On click listener onClick) {
CheckBox.isChecked(item.isChecked):
itemView.setOnClickListener(onClick) ;
} 
 }


public class RecyleclerItem {
private <YOUR ITEM TYPE> object ;
private boolean isChecked ;

} 

onBindViewHolder(holder,  position) {
RecyclerView item = itemList.get(position);
holder.bindItem(item, v-> {
item.isChecked =! item.ischecked;
notifyItemChenged(position);
} 
}
```

Comment: Ответ плохо форматирован,  так как набирал его с телефона,  но надеюсь саму идею смог донести

Comment: Не могли бы вы пояснить, что значит **v->** ?

Comment: @Denis422 это лямбда выражение